# Update value in DOM after updating collection in Meteor

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I have a toggle button in React using the [react-toggle-button](https://gdowens.github.io/react-toggle-button/) plugin.

When you click on this button, it updates the value in the collection in the DB.

The thing is, the update doesn't reflect in the DOM unless you refresh the page.

Is there a way to get that data to update the value instantly so that the toggle actually visually toggles?

Here's the code for the button:

```
<ToggleButton

    value={d.showInClientMenu}

    onToggle={value => {
        Reports.update(
            { _id: d._id },
            { $set: { showInClientMenu: !value } }
            );
        value = !value
    }}

/>
```

If I click on this button and refresh the page, the button display the value that is now different, but the users won't know that the change has happened unless it's reflected immediately.

Comment: If you want reactive (instant) updates, you best be going with a publication / subscription on that collection. https://guide.meteor.com/data-loading.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to try with Meteor [`Publish and subscribe`](https://docs.meteor.com/api/pubsub.html) as like on the collection API, if the collection is `lists` then

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';

export const Lists = new Mongo.Collection('lists');

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.publish('lists', function () {
    return Lists.find({ userId: this.userId });
  });
}
```

and in the `imports/ui/ListsItem.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Tracker } from 'meteor/tracker';
import { Links } from '../api/lists';

export default class ListsItem extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      lists: []
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.listsTracker = Tracker.autorun(() => {
      Meteor.subscribe('lists'); // Auto publish when loggedin
      const lists = Lists.find({}).fetch();
      this.setState({ lists });
    });
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.linksTracker.stop(); // Stop publish when logged out
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Lists</p>
        <div>
          // Here is the view code and toggle
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

This was just an example which is how [`Publish and subscribe`](https://docs.meteor.com/api/pubsub.html) is work actually.

After implementing like this then the data automatically show after create or change immediately.

Also, read this

- [componentDidMount()](http://developmentarc.gitbooks.io/react-indepth/content/life_cycle/birth/post_mount_with_component_did_mount.html)
- [componentWillUnmount()](http://developmentarc.gitbooks.io/react-indepth/content/life_cycle/death_unmounting_indepth.html)

I think it will help.

Comment: Do you mean to say Lists instead of Links at the Meteor.isServer function?

Comment: @LukeVenter Yes! exactly this is like `Lists`